# Evaluating nested property calls from a string

Tags: c#, python, reflection, roslyn

I am currently reading the "500 Lines or Less" [book](http://aosabook.org/en/500L), the [chapter](http://aosabook.org/en/500L/pages/a-template-engine.html) for creating a Template Engine from Ned Batchelder.

Their example is using Python. In their template engine they are building code as a string and then they are calling `exec` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/exec.html)) to evaluate the string as Python code.

```
def get_globals(self):
    """Execute the code, and return a dict of globals it defines."""
    # A check that the caller really finished all the blocks they started.
    assert self.indent_level == 0
    # Get the Python source as a single string.
    python_source = str(self)
    # Execute the source, defining globals, and return them.
    global_namespace = {}
    exec(python_source, global_namespace)
    return global_namespace
```

This is very convenient, because they can easily evaluate expressions in the template such as `{{object.property.property}}`

With C# as my main programming language I am wondering how can this be achieved (in the context of building a template engine as in the book)?

**Research and thoughts**

First I don't believe there is an `exec` equivalent in C#.

One way I can think of it is to recursively use Reflection to get the List of properties of an object (handling checks for Null References), but I don't like this from performance point of view.

Another way is to use Roslyn's `ScriptEngine` class (which I haven't used so correct me if I am wrong). But I am afraid that this won't be good because this is supposed to be a library and it won't be able to be used with older versions of C# and .NET. [Example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2011/12/02/introduction-to-the-roslyn-scripting-api.aspx)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure anymore if the ScriptEngine class is still available (or supported) -- the scripting feature was scrapped some time ago and is only recently reintroduced. You can find the properly supported scripting engine here: https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: First I don't believe there is an exec equivalent in C#.

As for compling `C#` code, [`CS-Script`](http://www.csscript.net/) library can be used to achieve this in various ways.

For example:

```
dynamic script = CSScript.Evaluator
                         .LoadCode(@"using System;
                                     using Your.Custom.Relevant.Namespace;
                                     public class Executer
                                     {
                                         public object Execute()
                                         {
                                             return SomeStaticClass.array[123];
                                         }
                                     }");
int result = script.Execute();

//shorter way
int a = (int)CSScript.Evaluator.Evaluate("some.namespace.SomeStaticClass.array[123]");
```

Read more here: http://www.csscript.net/

`CS-Script` **isn't** made for templating.
Unless you create it yourself by manipulating the strings before you compile them.

> But how can I pass some Context for the template engine

You can pass a context into a function like this:

```
dynamic script = CSScript.Evaluator
                     .LoadCode(@"
                                using System;
                                using Namespace.Of.The.Context;
                                public class Executer {
                                    public string Execute(Context ctx) {
                                        return ctx.Person.Firstname + ctx.Person.Lastname;
                                    }
                                }");
int result = script.Execute(new Context(new Person("Rick", "Roll")));
```

> Q: Can I call CSScript from a normal C# application lets say a Web App?
>
> A: Yes.
>
> S-Script currently targets Microsoft implementation of CLR (.NET
>   2.0/3.0/3.5/4.0/4.5) with full support on Mono.

Basically if it runs C#, it can be compiled accordingly to the .net-framework that the library is executed on, so if your project is ran on .net4.5, any feature of that .net version is available including any external references in your project too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But how can I pass some Context for the template engine - An object created outside of the CSScript? For example the template has {{person.Address.Town}} and my Context has a key "person" with an object of type Person. Can I call CSScript from a normal C# application lets say a Web App?

Comment: May be I see a way of doing it using CSScript. Although I seriously doubt that is is faster than reflection for the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider` in order to compile code on fly.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx

Like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string source =
        @"
            namespace Test
            {
                public class Test
                {
                    public void HelloWorld()
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine(""Hello World"");
                    }
                }
            }
        ";

        var options = new Dictionary<string, string> {  {"CompilerVersion", "v3.5"} };
        var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(options);
        var compilerParams = new CompilerParameters{GenerateInMemory = true,  GenerateExecutable = false };
        var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, source);
        var method = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("Test.Test");
        var methodInfo = method.GetType().GetMethod("HelloWorld");
        methodInfo.Invoke(method, null);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But as it is with NucS, how can I pass some Context for the template engine - An object created outside of the string source ? For example the template has {{person.Address.Town}} and my Context is a Dictionary with a key "person" with an object of type Person.